# Rails Routing: How to rename the params-Hash keys in a (nested) resource block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, routes

Is there a way to rename the key for a resource in a resource-block? My routes for pages looks like this

```
get ':slug', to: 'pages#show', as: :pages
resources :pages
```

So for the show-action the key is not `/pages/:id` but `/pages/:slug` as described here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes.

Is there a way to change the params-key for all /pages/* routes to `:slug` instead of `:id`

Especially: Is this possible in nested resource blocks?

For example:

```
resources :users do
  resources :products do (should be params[:product_id] instead of params[:id])
    resources :comments (should be params[:comment_id] instead of params[:id])
    end
  end
end
```

Would be quite work-intensive to set all the routes manually just to change the params-key for that resource!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey – a good way you can do this is

```
# config/routes.rb

resources :pages, param: :slug
```

You can read some more about it here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to explicitly provide the name of the route:

```
put 'pages/:some_other_name_for_the_id', action: :do_something, as: :route_name
```

Using the `param:` option (mentioned by Damilare) is definitely preferred if it works for your use-case.